# Publish verification results to pact broker is not working in pact-jvm-provider-spring_2.12

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pact

I am trying to publish the verification results to pact broker with pact for jvm/spring.
I am using junit4.
The test is executed and passed, A verification report is printed to console/ json file is added, but it's not publishing the results to pact broker.

In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
    <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-spring_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.24</version>
</dependency>
```

In TestContract.class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("prov_test")
@PactBroker(host="192.168.132.220",port="80")
@VerificationReports({"console", "json"})
@SpringBootTest(
    properties={
        "pact.provider.version=1.0.1",
        "pact.verifier.publishResults=true"
    },
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.webEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT
)
public class TestContract {
...
...
}
```

In the output I get the warnning:

```
Skipping publishing of verification results (pact.verifier.publishResults is not set to 'true')
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We're junit5 and had to set it in the @BeforeEach to get it to work :

```
    void setupTestTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", port, "/"));
        System.setProperty("pact.verifier.publishResults", "true");
        System.setProperty("pact.provider.version", buildVersion);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `pact.verifier.publishResults=true` to `pact.verifier.publishResults='true'`

See this [github thread](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/724#issuecomment-402326441)

Comment: changed to `"pact.verifier.publishResults='true'"` but still not working. I also still get the warning "Skipping publishing of verification results (pact.verifier.publishResults is not set to 'true'"..